# What does "each step is Man Friday on the move" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> But if you prefer more of a real desert golf experience, a visit to Al Ghazal, Abu Dhabi’s all-sand course, is an eye-opener, although pleasure is not guaranteed: balls hit off stones, grit or a small square of artificial turf fly off at random. ‘Browns’, sand putting surfaces slicked smooth with oil, are true, but each step is Man Friday on the move, the deep imprints requiring extensive sweeping to restore the status quo.

[Source: Distinctnews](http://distinctnews.com/uncategorized/the-golf-course-thats-abu-dhabis-answer-to-st-andrews/)

I looked up *man* *friday* and it means a loyal servant. I then traced the origin to the movie Robinson Crusoe as [explained on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-did-the-term-Man-Friday-originate)

I didn't watch the movie but I'm guessing Man Friday stomped for his life.

Comment: It sounds like this: imagine Hulk (the green comic book guy) stomping around - it's hard to keep the sand nice and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

In Daniel Defoes's book *Robinson Crusoe*, the eponymous hero meets Man Friday on a beach, having followed his footprints (iirc). This is rather obscure (and pretentious) prose. However, we can interpret "each step is a Man Friday on the move" as:

> each step creates a trail of footprints

**Edit:**

Looking at the Wikipedia article on *Robinson Crusoe*, it appears that Crusoe frees Man Friday from cannibals (on a Friday), so this rather negates my logic. I do remember a similar story where the hero discovers someone on a beach by following a trail of footprints, but I cannot remember the name of the story. Maybe the writer of the article also got his stories muddled.

[Wikipedia: Robinson Crusoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_Crusoe)

Comment: Crusoe first discovers that there is another person on the island when he sees a footprint in the sand which he knows is not his own.